# Locust load testing : How to allocate single user for one particular API among all other APIs

Tags: load-testing, locust

I need to test set of APIs with below scenarios using locust.

1. There are 8 HTTP GET APIs as below.

```
    1. "/v1/api_1"
    2. "/v1/api_2"
    3. "/v1/api_3"
    4. "/v1/api_4"
    5. "/v1/api_5"
    6. "/v1/api_6"
    7. "/v1/api_7"
    8. "/v1/api_8"
```

2. I need to allocate 3 users and those 3 users should call the 1st five APIs
3. Those 5 APIs should call with 15 second wait time with given weight.
4. I need to allocate another 3 users for the last 3 APIs and one user should responsible for 1 API.
5. Each of the last 3 APIs should call in every 5 second.

Please see below image for more details

[image]

How should I achieve above scenarios using locust.

Below is my code.

```
class API_User(TaskSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @task(10)
    def get_api_1(self):
        print(f"/v1/api_1")
        time.sleep(15)

    @task(50)
    def get_api_2(self):
        print(f"/v1/api_2")
        time.sleep(15)

    @task(20)
    def get_api_3(self):
        print(f"/v1/api_3")
        time.sleep(15)

    @task(10)
    def get_api_4(self):
        print(f"/v1/api_4")
        time.sleep(5)

    @task(10)
    def get_api_5(self):
        print(f"/v1/api_5")
        time.sleep(5)

    @task
    def get_api_6(self):
        print(f"/v1/api_6")
        time.sleep(5)

    @task
    def get_api_7(self):
        print(f"/v1/api_7")
        time.sleep(5)

    @task
    def get_api_8(self):
        print(f"/v1/api_8")
        time.sleep(5)

class API_User_Test(User):
    tasks = {API_User}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making it too complicated. Each individual http call doesn't have to be its own task. You can make a task a bunch of calls plus things to do in between. Make a task for each of the different scenarios ("users" as you're terming it) you need to be run. That means a single task for calling the first five APIs with appropriate sleep times. Weight tasks appropriately and then start the number of Locust users you want to run. Using your example code:

```
class API_User(TaskSet):

    @task(3)
    def get_api_1(self):
        print(f"/v1/api_1")
        time.sleep(15)
        print(f"/v1/api_2")
        time.sleep(15)
        print(f"/v1/api_3")
        time.sleep(15)
        print(f"/v1/api_4")
        time.sleep(5)
        print(f"/v1/api_5")
        time.sleep(5)

    @task(1)
    def get_api_6(self):
        print(f"/v1/api_6")
        time.sleep(5)

    @task(1)
    def get_api_7(self):
        print(f"/v1/api_7")
        time.sleep(5)

    @task(1)
    def get_api_8(self):
        print(f"/v1/api_8")
        time.sleep(5)

 class API_User_Test(User):
    tasks = {API_User}
```

Also, if you're not doing anything else in `__init__` other than calling super's init, you don't need that.

Comment: Could you please give an example

Comment: Edited my answer to add an example